# multiple times statement execution in Component.onCompleted qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have an rectangle in which I am calling a statement on its onComplted block. But I dont know the statement gets executed 3 times instead of only 1. Here is my code

```
Rectangle {

    id: selector_button;

    signal clicked  
    state: 'pressed'

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent;

        onPressed: {
            selector_button.state == 'pressed' ? selector_button.state = "" : selector_button.state = 'pressed';
            Current.currentData("Enbaled"); 
            selector_button.clicked();
        }
    }
    states: [
        State {
            name: "pressed"
            PropertyChanges { target: selector_button; color: "#fg08Rf" }
        }
    ]

    Component.onCompleted: {
        Current.currentData("Enabled"); */
    }
}
```

But I use this component in other qml files as well, is it the issue...? if yes where shall I call this statement so that it executes only once
Similar things are happening on some onPropertyChanged ...any idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking here.  Are you saying that your onCompleted handler is being called three times despite only initiating the rectangle once?

Comment: It seems so that onCOmpleted handler is been called three times and it is making real performance issues..

Comment: Again, is this component instantiated only once in your program, or multiple times?

Comment: I checked it , it is component instantiate multiple times ..which results in same statement executing many time..

Comment: Component.onCompleted will be called each time an instance of your rectangle is created -- what you're seeing here is the expected behavior.

Comment: the State Fast Forwarding operation causes this issue. I faced multiple times to this issues specially on Loader item which causes unwanted behaviour. does anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the state fast forwarding, the qml engine parsing and initialized EACH state before rendering phase.

Ref.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativestates.html#state-fast-forwarding

This is more like undefined behavior of QML, and your logic or value binding should not rely on this "feature"

Comment: btw, I just test on 5.3 clang, only one statement is executed.

Comment: but this is real issue, that is causing real performance issues, for example in Component.onCOmpleted handler I am processing some json string and if it executes three time it will add delay for sure and app would be slow

Comment: @JNI_onLoad The easiest way I would suggest is to upgrade you Qt to latest one, but if you are locked on one particular version.

1. remove qml build-in state propery, and roll out your own. something like:

property bool state: true
onPressed: {selector_button.state = false; selector_button.color=foo}

or if you fsm is too complex, use some js library to hold a js fsm,
https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine


2. another way is processing the json on a separate object, outside the scope of the one that has state property, and do the assignment in the onComplete.